# Add A 2D Array to Array List of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Edit: Array List declaration:

```
List<String> shapeList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I'm trying to create an array of 2D arrays using an array list.

```
shapeList.add(drawBoxClassObject.drawBox(l));
```

Where drawBoxClassObject.drawBox(l); returns a 2D string array, this line gives me this error:

```
no suitable method found for add(String[][])
method Collection.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[][] cannot be converted to String)
method List.add(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String[][] cannot be converted to String)
```

How can I store the 2D string array itself inside a 1D string array (which I think would fix the cannot be converted to String)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error shows that your `shapeList` is initialized somewhat like this:

```
List<String> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

But if you want to store `drawBoxClassObject`, then you need to change declaration to accept 2D string array, like this:

```
List<String[][]> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration of `shapeList` from

```
List<String> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
List<String[][]> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    List<String[][]> shapeList = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
```

You are putting a String[][] not a String.